# Simple text processing task in perl/Visual Basic

Tags: vb.net, perl

I have a long string containing a bibliography, alternating between lines of paper-title/comma-separated-author-list, like the following:

```
Learning Programs: A Bayesian Approach
P. Liang, M. Jordan, D. Klein
Variational methods for a Dirichelet process
D. Blei, M. Jordan
```

What I want is a list of unique authors (alphabetized by last name) and counts.  In the above example it would be:

```
D. Blei (1)
M. Jordan (2)
D. Klein (1)
P. Liang (1)
```

Can anyone tell me how to do this in Perl or visual basic?  Thanks so much -- you rock!!!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

In perl, what you'll need to do is read through the input, making every other line the author line:

```
my %list;
while (<DATA>) {
    chomp;
    my $book = $_;
    chomp(my $authors = <DATA>);
    map { push @{$list{$_}}, $book } split /,\s*/, $authors;
}

for (sort { sortA($a) cmp sortA($b) } keys %list) {
    printf "$_ (%s)\n", scalar @{$list{$_}};
}

sub sortA {
     if ($_[0] =~ / (\w+)/) {
        return $1;
    }
 }

__DATA__
Learning Programs: A Bayesian Approach
P. Liang, M. Jordan, D. Klein
Variational methods for a Dirichelet process
D. Blei, M. Jordan
```

Answer (score 1):

Worked for me:

```
#!/usr/bin/perl
use strict;
use warnings;

### collecting all the authors, using them as hash slice keys for quick count
my %author_count;
while (<DATA>) {
  chomp( my $authors_line = <DATA> );
  $_++ for @author_count{split /, /, $authors_line};
}

### printing the resulting hash 
### sorting by substr was sufficient for test cases, 
### but may be replaced by regexers, of course. )
print "$_ ($author_count{$_})", "\n" 
  for sort { (substr $a, 3) cmp (substr $b, 3) } keys %author_count;

__DATA__
Learning Programs: A Bayesian Approach
P. Liang, M. Jordan, D. Klein
Variational methods for a Dirichelet process
D. Blei, M. Jordan
```